# String interpolation with ternary conditional operator

Tags: c#

I want to create a datetime string but add CET/CEST depending if it's daylight savings or not.

```
$"{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm tt"} {TimeZoneInfo.Utc.IsDaylightSavingTime(message.RegistrationTime) ? "CEST" : "CET"}
```

so if `IsDaylightSavingTime` returns true, append "CEST" string, if not, just "CET".

Is there an easy/quick way to do this?

Comment: Wrap the ternary expression in parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the ternary operator in `()` brackets when using string interpolation.  So the ternary operator in the string interpolation would become:

```
 {(TimeZoneInfo.Utc.IsDaylightSavingTime(message.RegistrationTime) ? "CEST" : "CET")}
```